# What is the intuition behind what Neural Networks do to data that is 1 dimensional?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Consider a data points $x \in R^1$. I am trying to understand what it means to share parameters across a batch of data that is 1D.

So in such a case we have:

$$ h = \sigma( w [x^{(1)}, ..., x^{(i)}, ..., x^{(B)}] + b )$$

where $w \in R^{D_{out} \times 1}$ and $b \in R^{D_{out} \times 1}$. If we expand it we get:

$$ h = \sigma( [w x^{(1)} + b, ..., w x^{(i)} +b , ..., w x^{(B)} +b])$$

where each coordinate out the output is of the form:

$$ h_{j,i} = \sigma( w_j x^{(i)} + b_j)$$

where its the $j$th output (row) for example $i$th (column).

What is making hard for me to understand is that:

1. The operation seems to be expanding every single number $x^{(i)} \in R^{1 \times 1}$ to a larger one $h^{(i)} \in R^{D_{out} \times 1}$. But this expansion is weird because in the linear case this wouldn't do anything interesting because it would span the same space...so I am having an issue interpreting what might be going on
2. it is true that $w$ and $b$ are being shared across data examples (or coordinates in the data vector) but I having difficulties understanding what that might mean.

Does anyone have a good interpretation of what might such a model be doing to such data?

I think I understand what convolution would do but the fact that the data is 1D and expanding it is odd...

Comment: Don't forget the activation function $\sigma$ that makes the whole thing non-linear. That way the function represented by this neural network can do different things to different values of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

[Jan](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/163572/jan-kukacka) has actually captured the essence of the answer in his comment, but I'll try to make it more explicit.

1. This is not specific to parameter sharing; it is what neural networks typically do. What this operation does is to produce a **non-linear** (assuming $\sigma$ being a non-linear function) dimensionality augmentation of the data. Now, why would you want to do that? For classification, your data might fall into linearly non-separable classes in the one-dimensional space. By appropriate transformation into a higher-dimensional space, they might become linearly separable. Below is a toy example: The classes A (red) and B (blue) cannot be linearly separated only based on their x-coordinate. If you artificially generate an y-coordinate, as $x^2$ (non-linear!), you can easily separate them: [image: dimensionality augmentation]

The same argument holds also for regression: You may not be able to find a good regression line (linear function) in the one-dimensional space, but in a higher dimensional space it might work. This is analogous to introducing non-linearly transformed values of the original independent variable as additional independent variables in linear regression, e.g.:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2$$

2. Parameter sharing here means that you are applying the same transformation on all components of your input vector. This can make sense when the absolute position of a value in the vector is irrelevant, but instead only its relative distance from other values matters. You can think of it as of, instead of presenting your network a single, $B$-dimensional input, you present it a sequence of one-dimensional values (scalars), which your network then augments into multi-dimensional vectors, always applying the same transformation, and stores them for further collective processing.